# How to overcome "undefined reference to _M_insert_aux()"?

Tags: c++, stl

I was compiling some c++ program where i have used push_back function. At the end I am getting this error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_vector.h:741: undefined reference to `std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::**_M_insert_aux**(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
```

In file stl_vector.h you will find _M_insert_aux but i couldn't find its definition.

Please suggest to me how to overcome this problem.

Code snippet:

```
for (table=lex->query_tables; table; table=table->next_global)
{
    string table_db=table->db;
    table_db += ":";
    table_db= table_db+table->table_name;
    current.tables.push_back(table_db);
    DBUG_PRINT("Dip", (" %s: %s, %s",table->db, table->table_name, table->alias));
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code that produces this?

Comment: for (table=lex->query_tables; table; table=table->next_global)
 {
  string table_db=table->db;
  table_db += ":";
  table_db= table_db+table->table_name;
  current.tables.push_back(table_db); 
  DBUG_PRINT("Dip", (" %s: %s, %s",table->db, table->table_name, table->alias));
        }

Comment: I am embedding some code in mysql

Comment: Please add the declaration of `current.tables`.

Comment: That was just a snippet..everything is done..The problem is coming from STL file..you can find it in /usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_vector.h at line # 749

Comment: Here you can see there is no definition of _M_insert_aux...May be this is the reason of error...

Comment: Could you post the compiler command that use to build?

Comment: Is this the only compiler error?

Comment: yap this is the only error...

Comment: You need to post a *complete*, *minimal* code example that reproduces this error, along with how you compiled the code. The error is definitely *not* in the STL header, it’s in your own code (or the compilation command). Your current question doesn’t have the necessary details to help you.

Comment: Well here is the command --->


sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mysql --with-plugin-partition --with-tcp-port=3308 --with-unix-socket-path=/tmp/mysql1.sock --with-debug CXX=g++

Comment: and as i told i have written some code in the MySql source code (file name-sql_parse.cc)..There i have used simple simple vector...One of the snippet i have given above

Comment: While i am doing "sudo make" i am getting the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced this compiler error with the following (`main.cpp`):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.push_back(std::string("test"));
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler command:

```
g++ -fno-implicit-templates main.cpp -o main
```

It compiles if `-fno-implicit-templates` option is not specified.

Check if the compiler flag `-fno-implicit-templates` is being specified and remove it if possible.

To build with `-fno-implicit-templates` I changed the source to:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

//class template std::vector<std::string>; TYPO here: 'class' & 'template' wrong order 
template class std::vector<std::string>;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.push_back(std::string("test"));
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

I downloaded mysql 5.1.60 and built it successfully using the `configure` and `make` commands you provided in the comment.

I then edited the file "sql_parse.cc" as follows:

```
// Added these include directives before any other.
#include <vector>
#include <string>

// At the end of include directives added this explicit template
// instantiation.
template class std::vector<std::string>;

// Added the following lines into a random function.
std::vector<std::string> v;
v.push_back(std::string("1"));
```

I then ran `make` again and it compiled and linked successfully.
Note I compiled with `-fno-implicit-templates`: I made no other change to the mysql distribution apart from the ones I made to "sql_parse.cc".

Comment: I did it but its not working...I deleted -fno-implicit-templates from configure file..And added that line (class template std::vector<std::string>;) but not working...Any other suggestions plz...

Comment: You only need to add that line if you specify `-fno-implicit-templates`. Did you run a `make distclean` or similar to remove all previously compiled objects?

Comment: yes sir i cleaned all previous objects...Now i cleared that line and delete -fno-implicit-templates but still error is coming..

Comment: When you run `configure` and then `make`, is the `-fno-implicit-templates` option definitely not present in the compiler command displayed during the build?

Comment: yes this command is not present during the build...And I have deleted that command in 'configure.am' file

Comment: Could you post the full `configure` command you used to build `mysql`? I just downloaded `mysql` source and want to try exactly what you did.

Comment: Well.i am working with MySql version 5.5.7-rc there we have **configure.am** file.Its a 19K lines of code so i can't post it here. But i made the change in line number 19048 and 19049 that is-->

Previously it was ->
**#CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -fno-implicit-templates -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti"**
Now i changed it to ->
**CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti"**....

My used command--->
**sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mysql --with-plugin-partition --with-tcp-port=3308 --with-unix-socket-path=/tmp/mysql1.sock --with-debug**

Then **Sudo make**

Comment: Currently downloading the same package as you and will attempt to build it at some point today.

Comment: you might be able to build it successfully..But in my case i have written some code in sql_parse.cc where i have used vector and all that..Please write some code in that file using vector, allocator etc.Then you might get the error...Can i have your email address please?